# Should I use a server method or Collection.insert() to insert a record using Meteor?

Tags: security, meteor

I'm trying to decide between two methods for inserting a new document to a collection from the client using Meteor.js. Call a Server Method or using the db API directly.

So, I can either access the db api directly on the client:

```js
MyCollection.insert(doc)
```

Or, I can create a new Server Method (under the `/server` dir):

```js
Meteor.methods({
  createNew: function(doc) {
    check(doc, etc)
    var id = MyCollection.insert(doc);
    return project_id;
  }
});
```

And then call it from the client like this:

```js
Meteor.call('createNew', doc, function(error, result){
  // Carry on
});
```

Both work but as far as I can see from testing, I only benefit from latency compensation (the local cache updating and showing on the screen before the server responds) if I hit the db api directly, not if I use a Server Method, so my preference is for doing things this way. But I also get the impression the most secure approach is to use a Method on the server (mainly because Emily Stark gave it as an example in her video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79uMp-S23MA)) but then the db api is available on the client no matter what so why would a Server Method be better?

I've seen both approaches taken when reading source code elsewhere so I'm stumped.

Note. In both cases I have suitable Allow/Deny rules in place:

```js
MyCollection.allow({
  insert: function(userId, project){
    return isAllowedTo.createDoc(userId, doc);
  },
  update:  function(userId, doc){
    return isAllowedTo.editDoc(userId, doc);
  },
  remove:  function(userId, doc){
    return isAllowedTo.removeDoc(userId, doc);
  }
});
```

In short: Which is recommended and why?

Comment: "In both cases I have suitable Allow/Deny rules in place": Allow/deny rules only apply to the db api, not to methods. "I only benefit from latency compensation if I hit the db api directly": You can get latency compensation with methods if you put the method definition in a shared location (i.e. not in the `server` or `client` directory). "The db api is available on the client no matter what so why would a Server Method be better?" In this case you would not set up any `allow` rules (and remove `insecure`) so that you can only access the db using the methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the method declarations under the `/server` folder, so they were not available to the client and this broke latency compensation (where the client creates stubs of these methods to simulate the action but in my case could not because it couldn't see them). After moving them out of this folder I am able to use Server Methods in a clean, safe and latency-compensated manner (even with all my Allow/Deny rules set to false - they do nothing and only apply to direct db api access from the client, not server).

In short: don't use the db api on the client or allow/deny rules on the server, forget they ever existed and just write Server Methods, make sure they're accessible to both client and server, and use these for crud instead.

Comment: I don't understand. Where in the video does she say that server methods are more secure than calling collection's methods? Under the hood, the collection's methods calls server methods! And why don't you want to use the collection's methods, but the server methods instead? I get the impression you've missed something; the collection's methods aren't bad to use (although you can't use them fro everything).

Comment: @PeppeL-G I didn't say that she said that, I said she gives server methods 'as an example' - you have 2 options, she uses that one, the rest is inference. But yes, you're quite right, I have 'missed something' (hence my question!). If you have knowledge on the subject I'd be grateful if you could summarise what you know as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about protecting yourself against the example she shows at 15:36? Checking data sent from the client is not something limited to server methods, that's something you must do for collections too (in the allow/deny callbacks), and you do it in the same way. The principle for her example could just as well be shown with a collection, and the protection against it would be similar (when a client inserts a document: check that the document contains the type of fields you're expecting it to have in the allow or deny callback).

Comment: The reason she uses a server method in her example is that she wanted to easily show how one can get all the information about a user without knowing the secret password for that user. With collections, a simple example would just insert illegal documents or delete all the documents in a collection; not as fun as knowing all the secrets a user has 3:)

Comment: Perhaps the video link was misleading, my reference to it was actually intended to demonstrate the vagueness of my thinking - not to use it to try and assert one method is better than another. If I understand you well you're saying both methods are valid, but which is recommended, and why? That's really what my question is. My answer summarises my current thinking: keep it simple, keep it on the server. But it's not a criticism of using the db api on the client, it's simply a choice to ignore/remove that feature because it's not required.

Comment: I would say go with the collection methods. By using server methods instead, you're kind of reinventing the wheel (using collections' methods on the client is not a bad thing, it's one of the seven principles of Meteor!). Your thinking "keep it on the server" still holds by using the collections' allow/deny rules on the server (there's no (security) reason for using them on the client). At the moment the collection methods has some limitations though (for example adding default values for records without using small hacks), but it's the right way to go.